How do I set the default mode for iwd on boot
Recently I’ve been using iwd instead of networkmanager for various reasons. Every boot, iwd defaults to ap (access point) instead of station (wifi)
Is there a way to set station as the default?
/etc/iwd/main.conf:
[General]
EnableNetworkConfiguration=true


can you post the content of your /etc/iwd/main.conf ?

It’s posted above

I fixed it by creating a systemd service starting after iwd.service containing the following:
iwctl device wlan0 set-property Mode station

